# Does android 4.2.2 support jre 1.7?

Tags: java, android

I have a handheld device with android 4.2.2. Now, I want to know is it possible to know which java runtime environment is supported on that version, as android is java based.

Actually I want to use java try with resource in my new developed app for android 4.2.2. So, I am interested to know is that working in there or not?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Android only support version of `Java 6` features of `Java 7` like `Switch-case` of string ,`try ressource management` or catch mutiple related exception in a simple catchfail.

Answer (score -1):

it support java 1.7 but if you include google map then you have to use java 1.6.

Comment: why you give vote down ?? can You explain me :(