# setContentView not working when click button

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

Pease help me with my code.

When i click any button, button1, button2 or button3 opens new activity, but layout is empty, without any text's and others.

Code of activity from calling the new activity:

```
package com.novator.inweld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TentsCatalog extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tents_catalog);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view == button1)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TentPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("tentId", "1");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if(view == button2)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TentPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("tentId", "2");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if(view == button3)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TentPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("tentId", "3");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Code of my new activity:

```
package com.novator.inweld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TentPage extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        String tentId = intent.getStringExtra("tentId");

        if(tentId == "1")
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent1);
        }

        if(tentId == "2")
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent2);
        }

        if(tentId == "3")
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent3);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

use equals(), not ==

```
if(tentId.equals("1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is a b*%$#ch... Use `equals()`:

```
if(tentId.equals("1")) ...
```

Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19462363/871910), Android supports Java 1.7's strings in switch statements, meaning you can rewrite your code in a tidier fashion:

```
switch(tendId) {
    case "1": ...
    case "2": ...
    case "3": ...
}
```

Keep in mind that the simplest solution would be to pass `tendId` as an int and not a string:

```
 intent.putExtra("tendId", 1);
 int tendId = intent.getIntExtra("tendId");
```

Answer (score 1):

change onClick method with:

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TentPage.class);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        intent.putExtra("tentId", "1");
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        intent.putExtra("tentId", "2");
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        intent.putExtra("tentId", "3");
        startActivity(intent);
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }
```

and use `tentId.equals("")`; for String check you must use `equals()` method and for number value use `==` like:

```
if(tentId.equals("1"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent1);
        }

        if(tentId.equals("2"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent2);
        }

        if(tentId.equals("3"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent3);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your TentPage like:

```
package com.novator.inweld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TentPage extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        String tentId = intent.getStringExtra("tentId");

        if(tentId.equals("1"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent1);
        }

        if(tentId.equals("2"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent2);
        }

        if(tentId.equals("3"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.tent3);
        }
    }

}
```